# Make UIView in the center of the screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to add a simple loading animation on top a my view..and want it to be in the center of screen(visible aria)..can anybody point me to the right direction.?
how to get the center of the window so that i can addSubview..?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Check center property of UIView. You can set your view center to viewControllers root view for example:

```
yourView.center = self.view.center;
```

Comment: loadingView.center = aSuperview.center;
loadingView.frame.size = CGSizeMake(300, 300);//when setting this Xcode throws an error Lvalue required as aleft operand assignment..im stuck at this..

Comment: oh that was my fault..i need to set the frame as whole like this.CGRect newFrame = loadingView.frame ;
 newFrame.size.height = 300;
 newFrame.size.width = 300;
 loadingView.frame = newFrame; Thanks Vladimir

Comment: loadingView.frame.size returns a CGRect, which is not a l-value. To set frame size you either need to use separate variable (CGRect newFrame = loadingView.frame; newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(); loadingView.frame = newFrame) or explicitly set all frame components:  loadingView.frame.size = CGRectMake(0,0, 300, 300);

Comment: That x,y positions in your CGRectMake confuses me.if i do like it,will it be on the top left corner of my screen..?how do i make it to center..?

Comment: set the size at first (by setting the frame), and after that move set the view center to the center of the screen - so it will be centered as needed

Comment: When i rotate the screen its not displaying correctly.do i have to redraw the whole thing again?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you really may need to adjust view frames on rotation - that may depend on autoresizing masks set to views

Comment: Using XCode 5.1 and 7.0 ios, I had to turn off Auto Layout on the controller for this to actually work properly.

Answer (score 10):

If you may want to control the center alignment of axis's separately, consider the below answer.

Center/align along the X axis

```
yourView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x,self.yourView.center.y);
```

Center/align along the Y Axis

```
yourView.center = CGPointMake(self.yourView.center.x, self.view.center.y);
```

Comment: Is there a way for doing this with .frame = CGRectMake(...) ?